# Remove top margin in multicolumn \enumerate

Tags: margins, multicol, enumitem

I am trying to combine the multicols and enumerate environments (alternatively, the multicols and enumitem packages). Basically, I want to get rid of the top margin when having enumerate inside of multicol. The usual settings, as shown below, fail. Thanks!

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
I can get rid of the margin here:
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt]
    \item a
    \item b
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{10pt}

but not here
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt]
    \item a
    \item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\vspace{10pt}

and
\begin{multicols}{2}
[not even like so]
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,nolistsep,partopsep=-20pt,topsep=-20pt]
    \item a
    \item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436), and thanks for providing a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can eliminate that via `\setlength\multicolsep{0pt}`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}
I can get rid of the margin here:
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt]
    \item a
    \item b
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{10pt}

and also here
{\setlength\multicolsep{0pt}%
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt]
    \item a
    \item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}}
\vspace{10pt}

and
{\setlength\multicolsep{0pt}%
\begin{multicols}{2}
[also like so]
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,nolistsep,partopsep=-20pt,topsep=-20pt]
    \item a
    \item b
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I observe that there is an extra space after the environment.

Comment: @SayOL: Which environment? Do you see this issue in the MWE I posted or in your use case? If it is in your use case, can you let me know how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I suspect it is produced by enumerate environment. Anyway, it is my own case! I declare in the preamble ``\setlist[enumerate]{topsep=0pt}
\setlength\multicolsep{\topsep}
\SetEnumitemKey{5}{before=\begin{multicols}{5},after=\end{multicols}}''

Comment: @SayOL: If you haven't figured out the problem, please aks a new question and add a reference to this.  I suspect it will get answered very quickly.  Make sure to include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem you mentioned.